# ArcMap 10.1 Create colored lines from one layer to another based on common field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, network

I joined a points layer to a polygon layer. How can I draw lines from a one-to-many polygon to points? I don't have Business Analyst extension so I don't think spider diagram is the right tool. Also, the polygon-to-points is not based on distance but is based on an attribute value in the polygon layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can run "Add XY Coordinates" on the Point data to add Point_X and Point_Y to the attribute table. I would create Polygon centroids by running "Feature to Point", add xy coordinates, "Add XY Coordinates". Next, Join the centroid point_x, Point_y to the Point Table using your attribute link.  Finally, create the lines by running "XY to Line", input the Point layer, point_x,point_y,pointx1,pointy1.